# how to hide this array sign ' [] ' when it is null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling a list of array from firestore and wants to hide this '[]' when it is null or I want to display some other text if it is null but it gets this array sign when there is no data. Thanks. Pic attached:-[image]

The code:-

```
    child:Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(hobbies != null?
                        "$hobbies":'Add what you love to do.....',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,)
                    )
```

Comment: Your array does not seem to be null but rather empty. Try to check something like `hobbies.isEmpty ? "empty, display your text" : "not empty, display the list content"`

Comment: I'll write an answer. If you can mark it as an answer, I would appreciate it. Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array isn't null, you should check if it's empty. That's why you have an empty array symbol and not an error.

I'm not sure if it's mandatory to check if `hobbies` is null. Indeed, I think Firebase return an empty array is there is a key but no value in the JSON. To be sure, you can add the null check.

```
child:Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: Text(hobbies != null && hobbies.isEmpty ? 'Add what you love to do.....' 
    : "$hobbies",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,)
)
```

Best

Comment: yes, have to add null check too with this.

Answer (score 1):

As Maxouille said,
you would better check null and empty.

```
child:Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(hobbies != null && hobbies.isNotEmpty?
                        "$hobbies":'Add what you love to do.....' : '',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,)
                    )
```